# Only some points inside of triangle are considered 'inside' the triangle

Tags: python, pygame, trigonometry

I've been attempting to make a simple pygame program that checks to see whether or not the cursor is inside or outside of a triangle.  I'm doing this by finding the area of the larger triangle, and then making three interior triangles from the mouse position to all three points and finding their areas.

From my understanding, if the sum of the areas of the three internal triangles is equal to the sum of the total area, then the point is inside the triangle.  However, my code is only returning that it's inside the triangle on specific pixels inside the triangle, and not the area overall.

I'm not sure whether this is a math error or a programming error, but here's the code regardless:

```py
import pygame
from math import sqrt

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

def drawTriangle(pointA, pointB, pointC, color):
    pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAY, color, [pointA, pointB, pointC], 5)

def getLine(pointA, pointB):
    return sqrt((pointB[0] - pointA[0])**2 + (pointB[1]-pointA[1])**2)

def getArea(pointA, pointB, pointC):

    AB = getLine(pointA, pointB)
    BC = getLine(pointB, pointC)
    CA = getLine(pointC, pointA)

    s = (AB + BC + CA) / 2

    return sqrt(s*(s-AB) * (s-BC) * (s-CA))

A = [100, 100]
B = [200, 100]
C = [150, 200]
Color = (255, 255, 255)

while(True):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            break

    mpx, mpy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    posArray = [mpx, mpy]

    drawTriangle(A, B, C, Color)

    Area = getArea(A, B, C)

    trigA = getArea(A, B, posArray)
    trigB = getArea(posArray, B, C)
    trigC = getArea(A, posArray, C)

    if(trigA + trigB + trigC == Area):
        Color = (0, 255, 0)

    else:
        Color = (255, 255, 255)

    pygame.display.update()
```

So far my best guess is that it's a rounding issue, but I'm not certain how to address that if it is.  I thought that by making the first if statement a <= would fix rounding errors, and it did improve the results, but it still wasn't perfect.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there could be some pixelation of the 3 new triangles where their areas 'overlap' and produce an area larger than the target. What happens if you were to multiply all the coordinates by 10 or more and then find areas?

Comment: @quamrana that wasn't the issue, the issue was originally that only specific pixels were shown as being inside the triangle, while the vast majority were not.  It was, somewhat as I suspected, an issue with the accuracy of the comparison, which  helped me with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use a more efficient algorithm to calculate the areas of the triangles. An algorithm can be found at [Check whether a given point lies inside a triangle or not](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-triangle-or-not/):

```py
def getArea(pointA, pointB, pointC): 
    x1, y1 = pointA
    x2, y2 = pointB
    x3, y3 = pointC
    return abs((x1*(y2-y3) + x2*(y3-y1)+ x3*(y1-y2))/2.0)
```

Note, you can still use your own algorithm, too. But

> ```py
> if(trigA + trigB + trigC == Area):
> ```

compares floating point numbers. Because of the limited accuracy of floating point numbers this test fails (See [Floating-point arithmetic - Accuracy problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems)).
You've to consider an *epsilon*. Do `abs(a - b) < epsilon` instead of `a == b`. It's not comparing the values of the two objects, but is instead comparing the difference to a value that is sufficiently low enough to virtually guarantee that the values are the same. e.g:

```py
if abs(trigA + trigB + trigC - Area) < 0.001:
    Color = (0, 255, 0)
else:
    Color = (255, 255, 255)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  If I'm understanding epsilon correctly, then it's not comparing the values of the two objects, but is instead comparing the difference to a value that is sufficiently low enough to virtually guarantee that the values are the same?

Comment: @NetherMan Yes exactly.

Comment: alright that actually makes a ton of sense, definitely something I managed to miss while learning.